# Application Crashes While Finding current Location on Button Click

Tags: android, google-maps, location, crash

My Problem Is while the app to running. The onClick function should call my position from GPS by longitude, latitude. But the problem is the app crashes when the button is clicked. What is the solution for this? I have tried to follow instructions from older Stack questions, but the error persists.

Here's the debug message:

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                               at
>   com.booleandev.googlfind.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:97)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```html
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == koordinat) {

            if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude : " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

     if (v == posisi_user) {


          LatLng user = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                user, 12));

     }
    }
```

this is my full MainActivity.java

```html
package com.booleandev.googlfind;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback,View.OnClickListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    Button koordinat;
    Button posisi_user;
    private final static int MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        koordinat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.koordinat);
        posisi_user = (Button) findViewById(R.id.posisi_user);

        koordinat.setOnClickListener(this);
        posisi_user.setOnClickListener(this);

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fm.getMapAsync(this);

        CekGPS();


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        } else {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
        }

        if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude : " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == koordinat) {

            if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude : " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

     if (v == posisi_user) {


           LatLng user = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                user, 12));


     }
    }


    public void CekGPS() {
        try {

                /* pengecekan GPS hidup / tidak */
            LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Info");
                builder.setMessage("Anda akan mengaktifkan GPS?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Ya",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {

                                Intent i = new Intent(
                                        Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Tidak",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // menampilkan status google play service
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else {
            // Google Play Services tersedia

            try {
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // Membuat kriteria untuk penampungan provider
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                // Mencari provider terbaik
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                        true);

                // Mendapatkan lokasi terakhir
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                if (location != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 0, this);
            } catch (Exception e) {


            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location lokasi) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        latitude =lokasi.getLatitude();
        longitude = lokasi.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS TURN OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

my activity_main.xml too

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    >


    <fragment

        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        />

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/koordinat"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Koordinat User"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/posisi_user"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Posisi User"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

the manifest

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Secret" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name=".lokasi">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".spalsh">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized the googlemap variable in on map ready 
Like  `this.googleMap=googleMap;`

```
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap=googleMap;
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
```

TRY THIS